# StackMate for iOS

Tags: app, iphone

**About**

The finest software programming Q&A website, stack overflow.com
 is now available on your iOS device!

StackMate is a full-featured Stack Overflow client with a minimalistic design and maximum functionality. Also featuring Push Notifications for the first time! This popular feature is used to send instant alerts to users when their questions are answered or someone adds a new comment. Push notifications are a great way to keep the users engaged and updated all the time. StackMate is the highest functionality client out there.

***Features include;***

- Navigate between multiple posts easily with Mobile Safari-like navigation
- Browse questions, answers, comments, as well as user profiles, activity, mentions and favorite questions on Stack Overflow
- Add questions to your favorites list and follow them via push notifications
- Flexible search to enhance user experience
- Question and answer contents are optimized for mobile

**License**

Commercial license, $0.99 on the App Store

**Download**

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stackmate/id455688984?mt=8

**Platform**

StackMate is compatible with iPhone, iPod touch, and iPad. Requires iOS 4.0 or later.

**Contact**

StackMate is a product of Pozitron. For more information please visit [www.pozitron.com](http://www.pozitron.com) or send us an email at ***stackmate [at] pozitron.com***

**Code**

Objective-c and iOS SDK with Python in the server middle layer. 
Third party code used:

- Three20 framework for iOS
- Google-code-prettify
- SBJson for iOS

Comment: nice app, i like the multiple window feature.  its arguably the best one out (or at least that I've found), though isn't "full featured" a little generous considering the read-only nature?

Comment: I know you have implemented all/most possible features (seems SE is keeping this to themselves for now), but "full featured" had me briefly hoping this one was different, and it seems at least one guy over at the app store was kinda misled.

I know nobody wants to put "sorry it doesn't do X" in the description, just feels like it took me unnecessarily long to realize this limitation is the case for all apps as of now.

Comment: Why is it not available globally?

Comment: Can you please include info about availability / discontinuation?